# Apache not working with Flask using WSGI mod

Tags: python, regex, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to use Apache as a Proxy server for my Flask Application. however i am having the error below...since i am new I have no idea where to start looking.

I am  not using any virtual envirnoment. its a Python3 Flask application.

Apache Logs

```
[Tue Jan 21 16:16:19.249067 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 3041002528] [remote 10.0.0.12:50757] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/sysinfo.wsgi'.
[Tue Jan 21 16:16:19.249609 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 3041002528] [remote 10.0.0.12:50757] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/sysinfo.wsgi'.
[Tue Jan 21 16:16:19.250245 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 3041002528] [remote 10.0.0.12:50757] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 21 16:16:19.250679 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 3041002528] [remote 10.0.0.12:50757]   File "/home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/sysinfo.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Tue Jan 21 16:16:19.251735 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 3041002528] [remote 10.0.0.12:50757]     from test import app as application
[Tue Jan 21 16:16:19.252221 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 3041002528] [remote 10.0.0.12:50757] ImportError: cannot import name app
```

**test.py is within WWW folder so is sysinfo.wsgi**

wsgi file

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www')
from test import app as application
```

conf file

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess sysinfo user=pi group=www-data threads=5
 WSGIScriptAlias /sysinfo /home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/sysinfo.wsgi
 <Directory "/home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www">
        WSGIProcessGroup sysinfo
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/logs/error.log
```

test.py

```
from flask import Flask
from views.address import address_blueprint


    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return "Hello World! 2"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Comment: You add /home/pi/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www to module lookup path, I assume you want the module being loaded there, have you place test.py in that folder?

Comment: Test.py is in www folder.

Answer (score 0):

on:  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file
it says also:

If a factory function is used in a **init**.py file, then the function should be imported:

```
from yourapplication import create_app
application = create_app()
```

with flask this seems to be the case...

if you continue to have trouble u may check nginx and waitress, or gunicorn
Have fun :)